# How can I add in a template object into a C# Frame template

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, contentview

Here is code I have been working on with the help of Deczalof:

Here is the XAML code that I have

```
<t:PopupEntryFrame2 x:Name="newDeckNameEntry" TextChanged="newDeckNameEntry_TextChanged" />
```

With code behind:

```
public partial class CopyDeckPopup : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    string originalName;
    string originalDescription;
    List<Deck> listDecks;

    public CopyDeckPopup(string clickedDeckName, string clickedDeckDescription)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listDecks = App.DB.GetAllDecks();
        newDeckNameEntry.Text = clickedDeckName;
        newDeckDescriptionEntry.Text = clickedDeckDescription;
        originalName = clickedDeckName;
        originalDescription = clickedDeckDescription;
        OK_Button.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private async void Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(false);
    }

    private async void OK_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;
        IsBusy = true;
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(false);
        var newDeckNameEntryTextTrim = newDeckNameEntry.Text.Trim();
        var newDeckDescriptionEntryTextTrim = newDeckDescriptionEntry.Text.Trim();
        if (newDeckNameEntryTextTrim != originalName || newDeckDescriptionEntryTextTrim != originalDescription)
        {
            App.DB.CopyDeckToDb2(originalName, newDeckNameEntryTextTrim, newDeckDescriptionEntryTextTrim);
            MessagingCenter.Send<PopupPage>(new PopupPage(), "PageRefresh");
        }
        IsBusy = false;
    }

    void newDeckNameEntry_TextChanged(object sender, EntryTextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewDeckNameEntryValidator(e.NewTextValue);
    }

    void newDeckDescriptionEntry_TextChanged(object sender, EntryTextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var deckName = newDeckNameEntry.Text.Trim();
        var isDeckAvailable = listDecks.Where(x => x.Name == deckName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (isDeckAvailable == null)
        {
            OK_Button.IsEnabled = e.NewTextValue != originalDescription ? true : false;
        }
    }

    void NewDeckNameEntryValidator(string newDeckNameEntry)
    {
        var newDeckNameEntryTrimmed = newDeckNameEntry.Trim();
        var isDeckNameAvailable = listDecks.Where(x => x.Name == newDeckNameEntryTrimmed).SingleOrDefault();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newDeckNameEntryTrimmed) ||
            isDeckNameAvailable != null ||
            newDeckNameEntryTrimmed.StartsWith("::") ||
            newDeckNameEntryTrimmed.EndsWith("::") ||
            newDeckNameEntryTrimmed.Count(c => c == ':') > 2)
        {
            OK_Button.IsEnabled = false;
            return;
        }
        OK_Button.IsEnabled = true;
    }

}
```

and the C# code for a template:

```
public class PopupEntryFrame2 : CustomFrame
{

    CustomEntry entry { get; set; }

    public PopupEntryFrame2()
    {

        entry = new CustomEntry();
        entry.SetBinding(PopupEntryFrame2.TextProperty, new Binding("Text", source: this));

        entry.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
        {
            OnTextChanged(new EntryTextChangedEventArgs(a.NewTextValue, a.OldTextValue));
        };

        Content = entry;

        CornerRadius = 5;
        HasShadow = false;
        SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "EntryFrameBackgroundColor");
        SetDynamicResource(BorderColorProperty, "EntryFrameBorderColor");
        SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "EntryFrameCornerRadius");
        SetDynamicResource(HeightRequestProperty, "PopupEntryFrameHeight");
        SetDynamicResource(MarginProperty, "PopupEntryFrameMargin");
        SetDynamicResource(PaddingProperty, "PopupEntryFramePadding");
    }

    public class EntryTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public EntryTextChangedEventArgs(String newValue = null, String oldValue = null)
        {
            NewTextValue = newValue;
            OldTextValue = oldValue;
        }

        public String NewTextValue { get; }

        public String OldTextValue { get; }

    }

    public event EventHandler TextChanged;


    protected virtual void OnTextChanged(EntryTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(PopupEntryFrame2), default(string));

    public string Text { get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty); set => SetValue(TextProperty, value); }

}
```

The error I get when building is this:

```
CopyDeckPopup.xaml(22,63): XamlC error XFC0002: EventHandler "newDeckNameEntry_TextChanged" 
with correct signature not found in type "DecksTab.Pages.DeckOptions.CopyDeckPopup"
```

Comment: You could look at [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview),it could achieve your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can simply add the `Entry` on your `PopupEntryFrame` `class` and define an `Event` there that connects with the `TextChanged` event in the original `Entry`.

This is done as illustrated in the code below (which is based on yours!)

```cs
using Test.Renderers;

namespace Test.Templates
{
    public class PopupEntryFrame : CustomFrame
    {

        Entry entry { get; set; }

        public PopupEntryFrame()
        {

            entry = new Entry();

            entry.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                OnTextChanged(new EntryTextChangedEventArgs());
            };

            Content = entry;

            CornerRadius = 5;
            HasShadow = false;
            SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "EntryFrameBackgroundColor");
            SetDynamicResource(BorderColorProperty, "EntryFrameBorderColor");
            SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "EntryFrameCornerRadius");
            SetDynamicResource(HeightRequestProperty, "PopupEntryFrameHeight");
            SetDynamicResource(MarginProperty, "PopupEntryFrameMargin");
            SetDynamicResource(PaddingProperty, "PopupEntryFramePadding");
        }

        public class EntryTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            // class members  
        }

        public event EventHandler TextChanged;
        protected virtual void OnTextChanged(EntryTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

    }
}
```

And that's it. By doing that you can now write code like

```xml
<t:PopupEntry x:Name="newDeckDescriptionEntry" TextChanged="newDeckDescriptionEntry_TextChanged">
```

---

### Update

In the comments someone suggested using `ContentView`, so let's take a look at how the same result could be achieved using that approach.

### Disclaimer

First of all, it is important to know that `Frame` inherits itself from `ContentView` (from which acctualy it inherits its `Content` property!). In fact, from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms) we know that

```cs
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Content")]
[Xamarin.Forms.RenderWith(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform._FrameRenderer))]
public class Frame : Xamarin.Forms.ContentView, Xamarin.Forms.IBorderElement, Xamarin.Forms.IElementConfiguration<Xamarin.Forms.Frame>
```

which means that by creating a Class/Control that inherits from `Frame` means that we are already using the `ContentView` approach.

### Create the ContentView

First of all we create a `ContentView` and set its content to a `new PopupFrame()` which itself contains an `Entry`, as follows

```cs
public class PopupEntry : ContentView
{

    Entry entry { get; set; }

    public PopupEntry()
    {

        entry = new Entry();

        Content = new PopupFrame()
        {
            Content = entry
        };

    }

}
```

### Add an Event

Next, as is required by the OP, we define an `Event` for our `ContentView` that will be triggered when the `Text` in the `Entry` changed. Following [the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/), this can be achieved by adding the following piece of code:

```cs
public class EntryTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // class members  
}

public event EventHandler TextChanged;
protected virtual void OnTextChanged(EntryTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    TextChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

Now, we can "link" the original `TextChanged` event from the `Entry` control to the new `Event` of our `ContentView`, as follows:

```cs
entry.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    OnTextChanged(new EntryTextChangedEventArgs());
};
```

Then, our ContentView code will look like

```cs
public class PopupEntry : ContentView
{

    Entry entry { get; set; }

    public PopupEntry()
    {

        entry = new Entry();

        entry.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
        {
            OnTextChanged(new EntryTextChangedEventArgs());
        };

        Content = new PopupFrame()
        {
            Content = entry
        };


    }

    public class EntryTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        // class members  
    }

    public event EventHandler TextChanged;
    protected virtual void OnTextChanged(EntryTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

}
```

### Wrapping up

With this `ContentView` defined, we can now write code like

```xml
<t:PopupEntry x:Name="newDeckDescriptionEntry" TextChanged="newDeckDescriptionEntry_TextChanged"/>
```

And that's it! I hope this was useful.

Happy coding!

### P.S.:

A little note about the Event declaration: Since EntryTextChangedEventArgs is a copy of the original TextChangedEventArgs we can define the EntryTextChangedEventArgs class like

```
public class EntryTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{

    public EntryTextChangedEventArgs(String newValue = null, String oldValue = null)
    {
        NewTextValue = newValue;
        OldTextValue = oldValue;
    }

    public String NewTextValue { get; }

    public String OldTextValue { get; }

}
```

and then when instantiating this class we just feed it directly with the values from TextChangedEventArgs, as follows

```
entry = new Entry();

entry.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    OnTextChanged(new EntryTextChangedEventArgs(a.NewTextValue, a.OldTextValue));
};
```